# Google Tag Manager for Android

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I implement Google Tag Manager on my project .When i work on emulator all events come faster in Google anlyatics account shown which page open,but problem is that when i use in real device its taking more time to show the events,its taking around 2-5 mins.

I am using like that can any tell me why its not working in real device.
& also can any one help me out how to implement E commerce tracking in android app.

```
DataLayer dataLayer = TagManager.getInstance(context).getDataLayer();
dataLayer.push(DataLayer.mapOf("event", "openScreen",
                    "screenName", "Home Screen"));       
GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context).setLocalDispatchPeriod(5);
```

Comment: Can anyone help me out regarding GTM implementation android.

Comment: @Mohammad, Did you find any help regarding GTM android

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, since I don't develop your Android, but for iOS using Google Tag Manager (and Google Analytics for that matter) the mobile platform is not pushing events in realtime, but they batch the data and send them every other minute or so. For me the emulator in iOS does the same, i.e. it sends data every other minute and the same on device. Maybe the emulator in Android is different in this regard, but I believe that mobiles do not send data in realtime at all, but batches a chunk of data and send it at the same time.

I don't think there is any way to go around this. Correct me if I'm wrong though, but that's what I read somewhere in the documentation. Can't seem to find the reference though.